# Rust TCP socket server only working with one connection

Tags: rust

I'm new to Rust and I'm trying to configure a simple tcp socket server which will listen to connections and will reply with the same message that received.

The thing is, this works as I want except when connecting with multiple clients.. The first client that connects will send and receive the messages but if a second client connects, the first one keeps working but the second never receives messages, in fact the message never gets in the code that will handle it. And if I disconnect the first socket, the server will start spamming forever that received a message from the first socket with the same content than the last message it sent.

I am pretty sure I did something wrong in my code but I can't find it

This is my server struct:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::io::Read;
use std::io::Write;
use std::net::Shutdown;
use std::net::TcpListener;
use std::net::TcpStream;
use std::str;
use std::sync::{Arc, RwLock};
use threadpool::ThreadPool;

#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
pub struct Server {
    id: Arc<RwLock<u32>>,
    connections: Arc<RwLock<HashMap<u32, TcpStream>>>,
    url: String,
    thread_pool: ThreadPool
}

impl Server {
    pub fn new(url: String) -> Server {
        let server = Server {
            id: Arc::new(RwLock::new(0)),
            connections: Arc::new(RwLock::new(HashMap::new())),
            url,
            thread_pool: ThreadPool::new(10)
        };

        server
    }

    pub fn start(&self) {
        let listener = TcpListener::bind(&self.url).expect("Could not start the server");

        println!("Server started succesfully");

        for stream in listener.incoming() {
            match stream {
                Ok(stream) => {
                    let mut self_clone = self.clone();

                    self.thread_pool.execute(move || {
                        self_clone.on_client_connect(stream.try_clone().unwrap());
                    });
                }
                Err(error) => eprintln!("Error when tried to use stream. Error = {:?}", error),
            }
        }
    }

    fn on_client_connect(&mut self, stream: TcpStream) {
        println!("Client connected from {}", stream.local_addr().unwrap());

        let mut id = self.id.write().unwrap();
        {
            *id += 1;
        }

        self.connections
            .write()
            .unwrap()
            .insert(*id, stream.try_clone().unwrap());

        let mut stream = stream.try_clone().unwrap();

        let mut buffer = [0; 1024];

        while match stream.read(&mut buffer) {
            Ok(size) => {
                println!(
                    "Message received from {} - {}",
                    id,
                    str::from_utf8(&buffer).unwrap()
                );

                stream.write_all(&buffer[0..size]).unwrap();

                true
            }
            Err(error) => {
                println!(
                    "Error when reading message from socket. Error = {:?}",
                    error
                );
                stream.shutdown(Shutdown::Both).unwrap();

                false
            }
        } { }
    }
}
```

And in my main.rs I'm just calling the connect function and the server starts working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this piece of code in your `on_client_connect` function, you're aquiring a read lock for  `self.id`:

```
let mut id = self.id.write().unwrap();
{
    *id += 1;
}
```

However, the `id` variable, which holds the lock, is not released until it drops at the end of the function. This means that all other clients will wait for this lock to be released, which won't happen until the function currently holding the lock has completed (which happens when that client disconnects).

You can solve this by rewriting the above code to only keep the lock while incrementing, and then storing the ID value in a variable:

```
let id: u32 = {
    let mut id_lock = self.id.write.unwrap();
    *id_lock += 1;
    *id_lock

    // id_lock is dropped at the end of this block, so the lock is released
};
```

Even better, you can use [`AtomicU32`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/atomic/struct.AtomicU32.html), which is still thread-safe yet does not require locking at all:

```
use std::sync::atomic::{AtomicU32, Ordering};

struct {
    id: Arc<AtomicU32>,
    // ...
}
```

```
// Fetch previous value, then increment `self.id` by one, in a thread-safe and lock-free manner
let id: u32 = self.id.fetch_add(1, Ordering::Relaxed);
```

---

Also, when the connection is closed your code goes into an infinite loop because you're not handling the case where `stream.read()` returns `Ok(0)`, which indicates that the connection was closed:

```rust
while match stream.read(&mut buffer) {
    Ok(0) => false, // handle connection closed...
    Ok(size) => { /* ... */ }
    Err(err) => { /* ... */ }
} {}
```

Comment: Thank you so much man! One more thing, I need to derive Clone for my struct but AtomicU32 does not implements this trait.. How do I fix that?

Comment: @GustavoHenriqueMoralesdeMe It should probably have been in my answer from the start but you'd just wrap it in an `Arc` (for the same reason as you'd do for the `RwLock`). Updated my answer to reflect this.